# greater than in case when in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use greater than in 'case when' in SQL?

I have the following which works fine, but for equal to 100:

```
select case (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,last_active,now())) when 100 then 'True' else 'False' end from sessions where uuid=11 and token='test';
```

How can I have the same query for (>100)?

Please let me know if you need more clarification!

Thanks

Comment: The condition which is "(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,last_active,now())) "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select case when (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,last_active,now())) > 100 then 'True' else 'False' end 
from sessions where uuid=11 and token='test';
```

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` has two forms.

```
CASE expression WHEN Value THEN Value [ WHEN Value THEN Value ] ELSE Value END
```

and

```
CASE WHEN Expression THEN Value [ WHEN Expression THEN Value ] ELSE Value END
```

You want the latter.

```
SELECT case WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,last_active,now())) > 100 then 'True' else 'False' end 
FROM sessions where uuid=11 and token='test';
```